# WordPress REST API - Modify JSON before importing

Tags: rest-api, json

Hi guys so I have some data hitting my WP from an external company at /wp-json/wp/v2/jobs/ to be imported as a post.

This data contains JSON that needs to be imported, however it tried to set taxonomies using strings e.g. "Manager" rather than the term_id which would be say "381". This means I get an error returned.

```
{
    "code": "rest_invalid_param",
    "message": "Invalid parameter(s): job_location, job_industry, job_sector",
    "data": {
        "status": 400,
        "params": {
            "job_location": "job_location[0] is not of type integer.",
            "job_industry": "job_industry[0] is not of type integer.",
            "job_sector": "job_sector[0] is not of type integer."
        }
    }
}
```

So what I want is when they post this value to us, for example:

> "job_sector":"Manager"

I want to instead loop through our taxonomies, and find the ID for this "Manager" job_sector, rebuild the JSON and **THEN** have WP import the data I pass, error free with the proper ID.

Can anyone help on how I can intercept the JSON and pass it along in the proper format?

I tried "rest_pre_dispatch" but this seems to be only editing the result sent back to them, it has already been processed by WP.

EDIT: Here is my code:

```
 function wpse281916_rest_check_referer( $result, $server, $request ) {
     if ( null !== $result ) {
         // Core starts with a null value.
         // If it is no longer null, another callback has claimed this request.
         // Up to you how to handle - for this example we will just return early.
         return $result;
     }

     $array = json_decode($result, true);
     $term = get_term_by('name',$array["job_sector"],'job_sector');
     $term = json_decode(json_encode($term),true);
     $termid = $term['term_id'];   
     $array['job_sector'] = $termid;
     $result = json_encode($array);
     return $result;
 }

// add the filter
add_filter( 'rest_pre_dispatch', 'wpse281916_rest_check_referer', 10, 3 );
```

EDIT2: After suggestion

```
    function wpse281916_rest_check_referer( $result, $server, $request ) {
        if ( null !== $result ) {
            // Core starts with a null value.
            // If it is no longer null, another callback has claimed this request.
            // Up to you how to handle - for this example we will just return early.
            return $result;
        }

        $array = json_decode($request, true);
        $term = get_term_by('name',$array["job_sector"],'job_sector');
        $term = json_decode(json_encode($term),true);
        $termid = $term['term_id'];
        $array['job_sector'] = $termid;
        $request = json_encode($array);
        return null;
    }

   // add the filter
   add_filter( 'rest_pre_dispatch', 'wpse281916_rest_check_referer', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: As an aside, you can figure out the ID via the REST API using the `job_sector` endpoints

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks! How would I start going about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `rest_pre_dispatch` hook is probably the most straightforward way to go, but you need to be careful about putting your new request data back into the `WP_REST_Request` object properly.

You were reassigning the `WP_REST_Request` object to an array of request data. Those changes are not persisted because the parameter is not passed by reference. Instead, you want to modify the `WP_REST_Request` object.

You can assign a parameter to the request object using array like syntax, or by using `WP_REST_Request::set_param( $param_name, $param_value )`.

You should also check to make sure you are only running this code on the correct route. I'd also move the priority to fire the hook earlier since you essentially are saying that this change should apply to everything happening on this request.

```
function wpse281916_rest_check_referer( $result, $server, $request ) {

    if ( '/wp/v2/jobs' !== $request->get_route() || 'POST' !== $request->get_method()) {
        return $result;
    }

    $job_sector = $request['job_sector'];

    if ( null === $job_sector ) {
        return $result;
    }

    $term = get_term_by( 'name', $job_sector, 'job_sector' );

    if ( $term && ! is_wp_error( $term ) ) {
        $request['job_sector'] = $term->term_id;
    } else {
        $request['job_sector'] = 0;
    }

    return $result;
}

// add the filter
add_filter( 'rest_pre_dispatch', 'wpse281916_rest_check_referer', 0, 3 );
```

Comment: Hi Timonthy, thanks for this the job seems to be going in but I get a blank response in postman and the software needs to get the right response or it wont know its been updated do you know why it would be blank? It seems $result is returning blank after I set the sector "$request['job_sector'] = $term->term_id;" but if I return $response before this point I get the proper response. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you modifying `$result`? The result returned from `rest_pre_dispatch` must be an empty value like `null`. That tells WordPress to continue processing the request and actually let the jobs route process your request. If you return the response now, you'll get a proper response back, but the job won't have actually been created.

Comment: Thanks for this, I aren't modifying result, but when I post in postman I get blank back, where as when I post without this custom script I get back all the post info that has been created - EDIT: I also just noticed in postman I get "500 Internal Server Error" top right!

Comment: If I remove all our custom code I get a response and a 201 Created which is correct, but with that custom code I get blank and a 500 :(

Comment: That typically indicates a PHP error. Could you check your error logs? Should be in `wp-content/debug.log`. You may have to add `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );` to your `wp-config.php` file. [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#Example_wp-config.php_for_Debugging)

Comment: Thank you, error in a custom plugin another dev team worked on. Works great now :D

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you looking for the [rest_pre_dispatch](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_pre_dispatch/) hook.

This hook allows hijacking the request before dispatching by returning a non-empty. The returned value will be used to serve the request instead.

From the docs:

```
$result

(mixed) Response to replace the requested version with. Can be anything a normal endpoint can return, or null to not hijack the request.
```

Seems like to you have to modify the $request and return null in order to no hijack the default response.

Comment: It seems that this only lets me edit the response back for the request, it doesnt let me change their INITIAL JSON  - BEFORE wordpress tried to import any of the data.

Comment: Could you add the full code in question?

Comment: Added my code! :)

Comment: Added to my answer :)

Comment: Amended my code is that what you meant? Doesnt work :(